# Overcoming PHP memory exhausted or execution time error when retrieving MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, out-of-memory, execution-time

I have a big table in my MySQL database. I want to go over one of it's column and pass it in a function to see if it exist in another table and if not create it there.

However, I always face either a memory exhausted or execution time error.

```
//Get my table
$records = DB::($table)->get();

//Check to see if it's fit my condition
foreach($records as $record){
    Check_for_criteria($record['columnB']);
}
```

However, when I do that, I get a **memory exhausted** error.

So I tried with a for statement

```
//Get min and max id
$min = \DB::table($table)->min('id');
$max = \DB::table($table)->max('id');

//for loop to avoid memory problem
for($i = $min; $i<=$max; $i++){
    $record = \DB::table($table)->where('id',$i)->first();

    //To convert in array for the purpose of the check_for_criteria function
    $record= get_object_vars($record);
    Check_for_criteria($record['columnB']);   
}
```

But going this way, I got a **maximum execution time** error.

FYI the check_for_criteria function is something like

```
check_for_criteria($record){
    $user = User::where('record', $record)->first();
    if(is_null($user)){
        $nuser = new User;
        $nuser->number = $record;
        $nuser->save();
    }
}
```

I know I could `ini_set('memory_limit', -1);` but I would rather find a way to limit my memory usage in some way or at least spreading it some way.

Should I run these operations in background when traffic is low? Any other suggestion?

Comment: Suspect that your MySQL query is not well optimized.  When you perform the query directly how long does it take to execute. How much data does it return?  Is it well indexed?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table` took 0.0006 sec

Comment: Nice! Do you really need *?  How much data is it returning?  Maybe PHP is having trouble parsing it?

Comment: @AllInOne About 90k rows .

Comment: That `*` looks suspicious though. Yes, maybe PHP is having a trouble there

Comment: and how many columns?  Also tell us about $nuser->save();

Comment: @AllInOne 32 columns. `save()` will create a new record in another table

Comment: AllInOne != 'laravel guy';  can you limit the number of columns returned?  32 columns * 90k rows = a lot for PHP to manage (perhaps needlessly)

Comment: When you comment out the save() operation do you still get your timeouts and memory errors?

Comment: @AllInOne it was caused by my first query to my big table. After discussing, I found the solution I just posted.

Comment: @ChristianMark You were right, I narrowed my query in the answer I just posted

Comment: Also consider pagination.

Comment: @j_mcnally it was not to `echo`

Comment: or if processing data do it in chunks by looping with limits, processing and then getting new data leaving old data to be GC'd

Comment: Even with distict, its possible at some point you will get a ton of distinct data and it will be a problem again, not sure what your data is, also distinct can be crazy slow.

Comment: @j_mcnally That's a good suggestion. Given the kind of data I have I think that distinct is the best solution but looping with limits could be a good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by limiting my request to distinct values in ColumnB.

```
//Get my table
$records = DB::($table)->distinct()->select('ColumnB')->get();

//Check to see if it's fit my condition
foreach($records as $record){
    Check_for_criteria($record['columnB']);
}
```